# Recurrence for permutation of A007306 (denominators of Farey tree fractions)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, recurrences

Let $a(n)$ be [A071585](https://oeis.org/A071585), i.e., numerator of the continued fraction expansion whose terms are the first-order differences of exponents in the binary representation of $4n$, with the exponents of $2$ being listed in descending order.

In the formulas section **Yosu Yurramendi** gives a nice recurrence:
$$a(2^m+k)=a(k)+[0\leqslant k<2^{m-1}]\cdot a(k+2^{m-1})+[2^{m-1}\leqslant k<2^m]\cdot a(k-2^{m-1}), a(0)=1, a(1)=2$$

I conjecture that there also exists another recurrence
$$a(n)=a(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor)+a(k)-a(k_1)+a(k_2)-\cdots+(-1)^ma(k_m), a(0)=1$$
where
$$n=(2k+1)2^{t_1}$$
$$k=(2k_1+1)2^{t_2}$$
$$k_1=(2k_2+1)2^{t_3}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$k_{m-1}=(2k_m+1)2^{t_{m+1}}$$
$$k_m=0$$
Also obviously
$$n=2^{t_1}(1+2^{1+t_2}(1+\dots(1+2^{1+t_\ell}))\dots)$$

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Your conjecture is based on what evidence? What numeric computations have you done?

Comment: The question title and the body of the question refer to entirely different sequences.

Comment: @Somos, thank you for comment! No counterexamples up to $10^6$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thank you for comment! See the last formula for A071585: it uses A007306 and two permutations of natural numbers.